# Excel macro is diplaying 'Run-time error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I understand there are many other threads for this but I don't know VBA code that well and I can't seem to understand the solutions provided. I been able to copy an existing macro from the web and use it on my computer with Excel 2013 fine, but once I try it on another computer with 2003 I get this error pop up. (Run-time error '1004' Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed) Would someone be able to let me know what I need to change in the code?

```
Sub ConvertToXlsx()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    ' Path must end in trailing backslash
    strPath = "T:\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do While strFile <> ""
        If Right(strFile, 3) = "xls" Then
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)
            wbk.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strFile & "x", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel **2003** is 15 years old. Why would you think code written in Excel **2013** would be the same? If you need compatibility between the two, write all of your code in Excel 2003.

Comment: Because I can't write code. I can only put pieces together from the web. Which is why I asking this question.

Comment: We're not a code writing service. If you can't write code, hire a contractor to write it for you.

Comment: I am not asking for someone to write code for me, just some advice on what I can change with the current code. You might be an expert in your field, but if you can't offer anything helpful to someone seeking some advice on a small problem such as this, without telling them to 'hire a contractor', then maybe you shouldn't  be commenting on it in the first place.

Comment: Maybe someone coming here asking for free help from strangers should be more polite.

Comment: Sorry. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

`FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.

Excel 2003 does not recognize (nor have) the `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` file format.

[`xlExcel8`](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/07/07/use-the-vba-saveas-method-in-excel-2007/) should work. Directly from the link:

> These are the main file formats in Excel 2007:
>
> 51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro’s in 2007, .xlsx)
>
> 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro’s in 2007, .xlsm)
>
> 50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007 with or without macro’s, .xlsb)
>
> 56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007, .xls)

Comment: Do I enter FileFormat:=xExcel8? Or FileFormat:=56? Because neither are working. Keeping in mind I am trying to convert .xls file TO .xlsx

Comment: @david_10001 - can you explaing "doesn't work" a little more. I just ran this line in the immediate window and it worked perfect: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\testfile.xls", xlExcel8`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use your line ^. I just used exactly what I have in my code above but changed the line FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook to FileFormat:=56 and then again with FileFormat:=xExcel8. But unfortunately both returned the same error.

Comment: @david_10001 - I am sorry. I just re-read your first comment. You **cannot** save an `xlsx` from Excel 2003. It does not even know what that is!

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Thank you for clearing that up. I'll look at updating our computers a bit. Cheers!